# Animation not working properly for dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

Animation of moving up and down using arrows not working properly,Moving up is animating properly but not moving down.

**Html:**

```
<div class="makeit_steps"></div>
<div class="row margin-top">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
            <span id="add-step" class="add-new">Add Step</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
            <span id="add-heading" class="add-new">Add Heading</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

Adding step dynamically:

```
$('#add-step').click(function () {
    $('.makeit_steps').append('<div class="row moving"><div class="col-md-12"><span class="steps">Step</span><span><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="105"></textarea></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></span><span class="step_remove">X</span></div></div>');
    $('.step_remove').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.moving').remove();
    });
    $(".glyphicon-circle-arrow-up").click(function () {
        var $current = $(this).closest('.moving')
        var $previous = $current.prev('.moving');
        distance = $current.outerHeight();
        if ($previous.length !== 0) {
            $.when($current.animate({
                top: -distance
            }, 600),
            $previous.animate({
                top: distance
            }, 600)).done(function () {
                $previous.css('top', '0px');
                $current.css('top', '0px');
                $current.insertBefore($previous);
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(".glyphicon-circle-arrow-down").click(function () {
        var $current = $(this).closest('.moving')
        var $next = $current.next('.moving');
        distance = $current.outerHeight();
        if ($next.length !== 0) {
            $.when($current.animate({
                bottom: -distance
            }, 600),
            $next.animate({
                bottom: distance
            }, 600)).done(function () {
                $next.css('bottom', '0');
                $current.css('bottom', '0');
                $current.insertAfter($next);
                animating = false;
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Adding heading dynamically:

```
$('#add-heading').click(function () {
    $('.makeit_steps').append('<div class="row moving"><div class="col-md-12"><span class="step_heading">Heading</span><span><input type="text" ></input></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></span><span class="step_remove">X</span></div></div>')
    $('.step_remove').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.row').remove();
    });
    var animating = false;
    $(".glyphicon-circle-arrow-up").click(function () {
        if (animating) {
            return;
        }
        var $current = $(this).closest('.moving')
        var $previous = $current.prev('.moving');
        distance = $current.outerHeight(true);
        if ($previous.length !== 0) {
            animating = true;
            $.when($current.animate({
                top: -distance
            }, 600),
            $previous.animate({
                top: distance
            }, 600)).done(function () {
                $previous.css('top', '0px');
                $current.css('top', '0px');
                $current.insertBefore($previous);
                animating = false;
            });
        }

    });
    $(".glyphicon-circle-arrow-down").click(function () {
        if (animating) {
            return;
        }
        var $current = $(this).closest('.moving')
        var $next = $current.next('.moving');
        distance = $current.outerHeight();
        if ($next.length !== 0) {
            animating = true;
            $.when($current.animate({
                bottom: -distance
            }, 600),
            $next.animate({
                bottom: distance
            }, 600)).done(function () {
                $next.css('bottom', '0px');
                $current.css('bottom', '0px');
                $current.insertAfter($next);
                animating = false;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.margin-top {
    margin-top:20px;
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-circle-arrow-up, .glyphicon.glyphicon-circle-arrow-down {
    font-size:30px;
    margin-left:25px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.add-new {
    color:#007acc;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.steps {
    font-size:16px;
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-right:20px;
}
.step_remove {
    font-size:16px;
    color:#007acc;
    margin-left:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.step_heading {
    padding-left:15px;
    font-size:16px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.makeit_steps {
    position: relative;
}
.makeit_steps .moving {
    position:relative;
}
.moving span {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

My fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/qupdjzcv/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to decide, whether you want to use the `top`-property **or** the `bottom`-property for the animations, and use the *same* property for both of the animations, otherwise you get conflicting declarations setting `top` *and* `bottom` to zero at once at the same time, that is mathematical not intepretable for the browser.

Try changing your JS to:

```
$(".glyphicon-circle-arrow-down").click(function () {

    (...)

    top: distance
    }, 600),
    $next.animate({
        top: -distance
    }, 600)).done(function () {
        $next.css('top', '0');
        $current.css('top', '0');
```

Comment: i want both,when i click up-arrow,swap the selected one with above one and when i click down-arrow,swap the selected one with below one

Comment: That's odd, can you give new fiddle with the changes please? I'm not registered there.

Comment: Erm, tested again, had a typo. Now changed `top+distance` to `distance` only, that works, updated quest, please try again.

Comment: yep,working fine now.But i am getting glitch if you too observe

Comment: I think so. I'd actually rather choose `margin-top` for the movements, set it to be `distance`, either as positive or negative value for the both elements, and then reset it to zero after their position-switch, like you do, already.

Comment: but i need to save the order too,which one would be better ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "save the order" and it might be a sepearate concern=new question. Is it, you want the position-order to be memoized and restored to its latest state, when a user re-visits the page? If so you have two options: 1.) User is logged in, you save the changements in the user-bound data on serverside 2.) User is not logged in, save it in a cookie, which binds the information to the used computer and the browser and is often destroyed, when users clear their browser-cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94321/discussion-between-raviteja-and-fmue).

Comment: Sorry, chatting is not an option to me. Just try to describe the wanted behaviour, you want to achieve.

Comment: what is best way to remove that glitch

Answer (score 0):

try this --

```
$('#add-step').click(function () {
$('.makeit_steps').append('<div class="row moving"><div class="col-md-12"><span class="steps">Step</span><span><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="105"></textarea></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></span><span class="step_remove">X</span></div></div>');
$('.step_remove').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.moving').remove();
});
$(".glyphicon-circle-arrow-up").click(function () {
    var $current = $(this).closest('.moving')
    var $previous = $current.prev('.moving');
    distance = $current.outerHeight();
    if ($previous.length !== 0) {
        //$current.insertBefore($previous);
        $.when($current.animate({
            top: -distance
        }, 600),
        $previous.animate({
            top: distance
        }, 600)).done(function () {
            $previous.css('top', '0px');
            $current.css('top', '0px');
            $current.insertBefore($previous);
        });
    }
    return false;
});

$(".glyphicon-circle-arrow-down").click(function () {
    var $current = $(this).closest('.moving')
    var $next = $current.next('.moving');
    distance = $current.outerHeight();
    if ($next.length !== 0) {
        $.when($current.animate({
            top: distance
        }, 600),
        $next.animate({
            top: distance
        }, 600)).done(function () {
            $next.css('top', '0');
            $current.css('top', '0');
            $current.insertAfter($next);
            animating = false;
        });
    }
    return false;
});
});

$('#add-heading').click(function () {
$('.makeit_steps').append('<div class="row moving"><div class="col-md-12"><span class="step_heading">Heading</span><span><input type="text" ></input></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></span><span class="step_remove">X</span></div></div>')
$('.step_remove').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
});
var animating = false;
$(".glyphicon-circle-arrow-up").click(function () {
    if (animating) {
        return;
    }
    var $current = $(this).closest('.moving')
    var $previous = $current.prev('.moving');
    distance = $current.outerHeight(true);
    if ($previous.length !== 0) {
        //$current.insertBefore($previous);
        animating = true;
        $.when($current.animate({
            top: -distance
        }, 600),
        $previous.animate({
            top: distance
        }, 600)).done(function () {
            $previous.css('top', '0px');
            $current.css('top', '0px');
            $current.insertBefore($previous);
            animating = false;
        });
    }

});
$(".glyphicon-circle-arrow-down").click(function () {
    if (animating) {
        return;
    }
    var $current = $(this).closest('.moving')
    var $next = $current.next('.moving');
    distance = $current.outerHeight();
    if ($next.length !== 0) {
        // $current.insertAfter($next);
        animating = true;
        $.when($current.animate({
            top: distance
        }, 600),
        $next.animate({
            top: distance
        }, 600)).done(function () {
            $next.css('top', '0px');
            $current.css('top', '0px');
            $current.insertAfter($next);
            animating = false;
        });
    }
});
});
```